# Does "or" being inclusive mean that I have to consider three cases?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I encountered this when trying to prove distributivity in the form of $$A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$$

$A$,$B$,$C$ being sets.
There might be a way to prove this using equivalance but I did it by try to show that every element $x$ in $A\cap(B\cup C)$ is also an element of $(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$ and vice versa.

Suppose $x\in A\cap(B\cup C)$. Then $x\in A $ and $(x\in B \text{ or } x\in C)$. Then should I divide the cases into $(x\in A) \land (x\in B)$, and $(x\in A) \land (x\in C)$. Or should I also consider the case where both hold? If I prove these two statement then the third has to be true but what could justify that I shouldn't mention this third case? This isn't the first time I encounter this but it's the first time where this caught my eye.

Is there a point where in the foundations of logic, we mention this equivalance? Or is "or" defined like this from the start?

Comment: You don't need to grapple with the issue for this proof.  If $x \in B$, then you have $x \in A \cap B$, so $x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$ and you don't care whether also $x \in C$, so you don't need to consider the case where $x \in B$ and $x \in C$.  If $x \notin B$, then you know $x \in C$, so $x \in A \cap C$.

Comment: Alternatively, by using the definitions of intersection and union and the distributive law, one can prove the two sets are equal by equivalence by rewriting $A \cap (B \cup C)$ as $\left\{x: x \in A \land x \in B \cup C\right\} = \ldots = \left\{x: (x \in A \cap B) \lor (x \in A \cap C)\right\}$, which equals $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend thinking of it like this:

Suppose $x\in A\cap (B\cup C)$.  Then $x\in A$ and $(x\in B$ or $x\in C)$.  (Just as you have it.)

Now there are fundamentally two cases:  Either $x\in B$ or $x\not\in B$.  If $x\in B$ then $x\in A\cap B$ and therefore $x\in (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$.

On the other hand, if $x\not\in B$ then since $x\in B$ or $x\in C$ then we must have $x\in C$.  To complete this case is very similar to the previous case.

---

If you are curious, case 1 covers both when $x\in B$ and $x\not\in C$ as well as when $x\in B$ and $x\in C$.  So in fact, although "or" is inclusive, a proof of a disjuction does not generally need three cases.  If one case is sufficiently general (as this one was above), then it automatically covers both the exclusive as well as the inclusive possibilities.